# how to php in stream publish -->facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to implement an array in the publishStream() function, but the code below is creating problems.

Any idea what's going wrong?

Thanks a lot

```
function publishStream(){
  <?php foreach($usernames as $username){ ?>
  streamPublish("Vote for me here", 'Please vote for me', 'Checkout', '<?php echo  $link.$username; ?>\n', "Facebook Application");
  <?php } ?>
}
```

Comment: What's this written in? Javascript?

Comment: yes. the file is a php file, but has some javascript and some php

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I see this as a problem

```
streamPublish("Vote for me here", 'Please vote for me', 'Checkout', '<?php echo  $link.$username; ?>\n', "Facebook Application");
```

Do you think you need quotes around `'<?php echo  $link.$username; ?>\n'` and why `\n`.

And moreover what is this `$link.$username;`. $something.$something. Is it a string concatenation or what is the data type?. If it is string concatenation, then quotes are not properly ended.